# Eloquent ORM Code Hinting in PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpstorm

So I'm just starting off with Laravel (using v5) and Eloquent. I'm working on getting some basic APIs up and running and noticing that a lot of working methods don't show up in PhpStorm's code hinting

So I have this model:

```
namespace Project\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model 
    implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {
}
```

And in one of my controllers I try to do

```
User::query()->orderBy('id', 'desc');
```

`User::query()` creates a Eloquent `Builder` object and `orderBy()` behave properly and without error. However, PhpStorm does not show `orderBy()` (or `take()`, `skip()`, and I'm sure others) when I type `User::query()->` and gives warnings when I actually do use it.

I am using [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) which has helped immensely with bringing code hints to the Facades, but not to the models/builders it would seem.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Have you set up scopes for project (inside phpstorm)?

Comment: @Kyslik Can you clarify what you mean by that? Project is set up just like any other project I've ever done (we mainly used Silex prior to this foray into Laravel). Everything else works correctly, just not these few items on the models and builders.

Comment: @JoshJanusch i'm experiencing the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Amitay No, I wasn't able to make any progress, unfortunately. I've just given up, pretty much. Too many things being called through `__call()`. Figuring out what is available to you in Laravel is really difficult, especially with how poor the documentation is and how little Ottwell documents method arguments.

Comment: @JoshJanusch after doing some more research i found that it's a phpstorm bug. i checked their latest version and it still has the bug.
hopefully they will fix it soon...

Comment: @Amitay Do you have a link to the bug in their bug tracker? I'd like to see what the cause is and track its progress.

Comment: @Amitay Another dev I am working with discovered that it is because `Eloquent\Builder` doesn't have all the methods (though does have access to them through `Query\Builder`). The easiest workaround seems to be calling `->getQuery()`. That will return a `Query\Builder` and give you code hinting, at least for normal SQL query building anyway

Comment: @JoshJanusch there are many issues open in the issue tracker, here is one https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19953.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

For future Googlers, and perhaps OP as well if you are still sticking to Laravel.

The [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package solves this issue for you quite elegantly, with what I believe is a relatively new feature; generated model PHPDocs.

You can generate a separate file for all PHPDocs with this command:

```
php artisan ide-helper:models
```

The generated metadata will look something like this for each class:

```
namespace App {
/**
 * App\Post
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $author_id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $text
 * @property \Carbon\Carbon $created_at
 * @property \Carbon\Carbon $updated_at
 * @property-read \User $author
 * @property-read \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Comment[] $comments
 */
class Post {}
}
```

This caused issues for me in PHPStorm however, where the software was complaining about multiple class definitions. Luckily an option is readily available for writing directly to the model files:

```
php artisan ide-helper:models -W
```

There are a few more options and settings available if you need to tweak the behavior, but this is the gist of it.

Answer (score 21):

Add in model PHPDoc`@mixin`

```
/**
 * Class News
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 * @mixin \Eloquent
 * @package App
 */
class News extends Model
{

}
```

In **PHPStorm** works

Comment: This is really a nice solution, seems to solve the problem without requiring an extra dependency, I think.

Comment: This should be the definitive solution.

Comment: `@mixin \Eloquent` doesn't work for me - it isn't recognized as a class. However I ended up using `@mixin Builder` (with `use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`), and that works - with the additional complication that I was using `[Model]::where(...)`, which for some reason also works, but to get rid of the PHPStorm hint I have to use `[Model]::query()->where(...)`. No idea what's going on here, but hey, as long as it works...

Answer (score 7):

If you're using BarryVHD's [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package, run:

```
php artisan ide-helper:eloquent
```

This will write `/** @mixin \Eloquent */` into the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php` file.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Laravel plug-in](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/01/laravel-development-using-phpstorm/) for PhpStorm and you need to specifically activate it in your project settings.

Comment: This definitely improved some things (route creation, config interaction, some additional Facade hinting), but it did not help with the models, unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion, though. This will definitely be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

A little late but I recently had the same problem so I thought I would put a note down:

This is because `Database\Eloquent\Model.php` has a `query()` function which returns `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` and the `Eloquent\Builder` has a line:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as QueryBuilder;
```

Then it uses 'magic' __call methods to call to functions in `Query\Builder`. (look for `__call` method in `Eloquent\Builder`)

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

> __call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.

So, indeed the method you are calling is inaccessible :) There is not much that the IDE can do.

There are workarounds like using @method tags but it is unmaintainable. An alternative is to use @mixin (but this is not standards based).
See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7558

I think this all be resolved when they get rid of all the magic calls in the Laravel code and use PHP 'traits' instead. [See last message here.](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/issues/35) :)

Answer (score 5):

Just import Eloquent Builder in your Model class and add mixin:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
/** @mixin Builder */
```

To cover all the models at once — add the mixin to the `src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to have some kind of explicit "casting" when interacting with the query builder. Example...

```
$user = User::query()->findOrFail($id);
$user->myUserSpecialMethod(); // <-- IDE syntax error
```

Since all my models are extending my custom base Model which in turn extends Eloquent, I've ended up creating this method in my custom base model:

```
/**
 * Explicit type-hinting
 *
 * @return static
 */
static public function hint(BaseModel $model)
{
    return $model;
}
```

This way, it solves the IDE invalid error and helps me:

```
$user = User::hint(User::query()->findOrFail($id));
$user->myUserSpecialMethod(); // <-- all OK !
```

Please note that this is not OOP type casting. It is only a hint to help the IDE. In my example, the returned `Model` was already a `User`. If I woud use this method on a derived class like `SuperUser`, only the IDE will be fooled...

An nice alternative also is to put meta information directly over the assignment statement:

```
/** @var User $user */
$user = User::query()->findOrFail($id);
$user->myUserSpecialMethod(); // <-- all OK !
```

Or next to it...

```
$user = User::query()->findOrFail($id); /** @var User $user */
$user->myUserSpecialMethod(); // <-- all OK !
```

Answer (score 1):

Verified on Laravel 8, just added @mixin Builder to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php annotation solved it.

```
// Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php
/**
  * @mixin Builder
*/
abstract class Model
```

Comment: Couldn't you just vote up [existing same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68130762/4774747) instead of adding another one? :D

Answer (score 0):

This really helped me ([laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)):

```
composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper -W
```

then :

```
php artisan ide-helper:eloquent
```

This really helps :

```
    Using version ^2.13 for barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
PS C:\Users\anonym\Documents\Github\laravel\elearny_app_web> php artisan ide-helper:eloquent                      
Unexpected no document on Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
Wrote expected docblock to C:\Users\anonym\Documents\Github\laravel\elearny_app_web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php
PS C:\Users\anonym\Documents\Github\laravel\elearny_app_web>
```