# How to declare columns on models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want my Code Completion (PhpStorm) to work with Eloquent models but if I declare fields corresponding to DB columns they no longer work:

```
class Limit extends Model
{
    public $id;
    public $type;
    public $limit;
}
```

Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is a slightly modified version of my own reply from this thread: [Eloquent ORM Code Hinting in PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31760673/4652136))

The [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package can be used to help with this issue, by generating PHPDocs for your models.

You can generate a separate file for all PHPDocs with this command:

```
php artisan ide-helper:models
```

The generated metadata will look something like this for each class:

```
namespace App {
/**
 * App\Post
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $author_id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $text
 * @property \Carbon\Carbon $created_at
 * @property \Carbon\Carbon $updated_at
 * @property-read \User $author
 * @property-read \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Comment[] $comments
 */
class Post {}
}
```

This caused issues for me in PHPStorm however, where the software was complaining about multiple class definitions. Luckily an option is readily available for writing directly to the model files:

```
php artisan ide-helper:models -W
```

There are a few more options and settings available if you need to tweak the behavior, but this is the gist of it.