# PhpStorm cannot find model's methods in Laravel

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, phpstorm

I'm running last version of PhpStorm and Laravel 5.6. Also I have the Laravel plugin enabled.

I have for example model `Book`. When I use `::where`, `::find` etc. PhpStorm yellows them out and tells that the method cannot be found in the model's class. How can I find this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eloquent ORM Code Hinting in PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439753/eloquent-orm-code-hinting-in-phpstorm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to laravel "magic" Ide have some hard time to figure out what's going on,

I recommend you to use this :

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

just follow the instruction and your ide will now have a better understanding of the framework.

You can also install some PHPStorm plugins related to laravel :)