# PHPStorm - Laravel Eloquent no code hinting

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

[Basically what's described in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439753/eloquent-orm-code-hinting-in-phpstorm)

In PHPStorm there is no code hinting for the eloquent methods - which is quite confusing (I am just learning Eloquent).

None of the provided solutions are working for Laravel 6+ it seems. Currently using Laravel 8. Wanted to push this topic again - maybe someone found a fitting solution already.

Code Example:

**app\Models\Article.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
use App\Models\Article;

$article = Article::where(...); //no code hint
```

Happens to pretty much all methods.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan ide-helper:models`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use laravel-ide-helper package (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper).

Install:

```
composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
```

Hinting for models:

```
php artisan ide-helper:models

php artisan ide-helper:models --reset
```

Use --reset option to replace whole phpdoc block in models.

Code hinting for facades methods:

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

Code hinting for classes called through containers:

```
php artisan ide-helper:meta
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use  get for fetch data after search with where sentence , so you have to use get at the end .
`$articles = Article::where(...)->get();`