# PhpStorm says find method not found

Tags: php, laravel, find, phpstorm, laravel-8

In laravel 8 I made a Model app/Models/Role.php

```
class Role extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

In routes/web.php I made route

```
Route::get('/role/{id}/user', function ($id) {
    $users = Role::find($id)->users()->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo $user;
    }
});
```

PhpStorm shows error saying "Method 'find' not found in App\Models\Role". Please help me to fix this. Thanks

[image: Show Screenshot]

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials how to configure PHPStorm to read laravel/php stubs and phpdoc. This is too vague for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its only `PhpStorm`  showing erorr.Ide is not able to recognize methods.If you call that route then get desired output.

To solve

> Method 'find' not found in \App\Models\Role

just call `query()` method

```
 $users = Role::query()->find($id)->users()->get();
```

`query()` returns `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`

Answer (score 4):

For Models in PhpStorm, this should be the definitive answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48847159/1382828

Using `@mixin \Eloquent` in your models cures all headaches.