# How to navigate Laravel model scopes in PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have a model `CheckingAccount` with scopes:

```
//scopes
public function scopeEmailLike(Builder $builder, $email)
{
    return $this->where($this->table . '.email', 'like', '%' . $email . '%');
}

public function scopePhoneLike(Builder $builder, $phone)
{
    return $this->where($this->table . '.phone', 'like', '%' . $phone . '%');
}
```

But PhpStorm fails to recognize them in other classes. For example here in controller:

```
public function all($filters)
{
    return CheckingAccount::query()
        ->emailLike($filters['email'])
        ->phoneLike($filters['phone'])
        ->get();
}
```

It says method `emailLike()` not found and `phoneLike()` is not even recognized at all. What is wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Some Classes and Methods will be created based on the functionality of your code and with calculation. PHPStorm or any other IDE is unable to recognize them. But if you know that the model has this method feel comfortable using it. It's doesn't cause any problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eloquent ORM Code Hinting in PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439753/eloquent-orm-code-hinting-in-phpstorm)

Comment: If you search for "*phpstorm laravel scope*" you will see many answers here. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/laravel.html.

Comment: 1) There is no real method `emailLike()` -- it is magic one (during runtime Laravel uses `scopeEmailLike()` instead).  Try declaring such method using `@method` in a PHPDoc for the class. 2) Consider using **Laravel Idea** plugin -- it's a paid one BUT it offers A LOT of features for Laravel development, especially for code completion. And it's in active development. At very least give it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Äs LazyOne said

1. There is no real method `emailLike()` -- it is magic one (during runtime Laravel uses `scopeEmailLike()` instead). Try declaring such method using `@method` in a PHPDoc for the class.
2. Consider using Laravel Idea plugin -- it's a paid one BUT it offers A LOT of features for Laravel development, especially for code completion. And it's in active development. At very least give it a try.